# Grab Exit Value

Tags: c

I'm still in the process of learning C language, and it's kind of tricky for me to deal with my current situation.

I created a global variable called `exitvalue` to keep on track the value. I know that I can use return, but I want to experiment without using return.

I want to keep track the `exitvalue` condition in every `if statement` by constantly changing the value either to 0 or 1.

Here's a snippet of my example code:

```
//Global variable
int exitvalue;    

int functionName() {
    if (some conditions) {
        // some codes....
        exitvalue = 1;
        exit(1);
     }
     exitvalue = 0;
}
```

The problem is why the `exitvalue` doesn't change to `1` after it gets to the if statement in `functionName()`? Isn't `exit(1)` kind of like break the statement and prevent it to set the value `exitvalue` back to 0?

Hopefully someone could explain this flaw that I made. Thanks.

Comment: The `exit` function terminates the entire program.

Comment: I tried to remove the exit(1) as well, but still exitvalue = 0 when I print

Comment: You'll need to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing the `printf` and the rest of the code, it's hard to know why it doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: `int functionName()` is supposed to return a value, for example `return 1;`. Please enable compiler warnings, and figure out what they mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to the library function `exit` will terminate the running program. If called with an argument equal to `0`or `EXIT_SUCCESS` it will return a successful termination status to the host environment. If it is called with an argument equal to `EXIT_FAILURE` it will return an unsuccessful termination status. If the argument is neither of these macros, the termination status depends on the implementation.

The `exit` function should be used for this purpose only, to immediately terminate the running program and signal a successful or unsuccessful program execution to the host environment.

If you want to simply return an integer value from a function, use the `return` keyword with an integer argument, e.g. `return 5`.

The code that you posted contains a function declared to return an integer: `int functionName()`. This function should therefore return an integer value and will accept an arbitrary number of input parameters. Note that in C, functions that accept no parameters **should** be declared with a parameter list of type `void`, e.g. `int functionName(void)`.

Since your code is missing a return statement it is technically invalid, the `exit` function is not used to return values from functions as I explained earlier. Also, removing the `exit` statement will not prevent the `exitvalue` global variable from assuming the value zero. It will be set to one inside the if-statement if the conditions are satisfied but will be overwritten back to zero once the `exitvalue = 0;` code is executed upon exit from the if-statement's block.

It seems to me that you want to simply monitor program execution, an easy way to do this is to add calls to `printf` at interesting places in the code. This can be done by including the system header stdio.h and performing calls like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void myCoolFunction(void)
{
    if (condition1)
    {
         printf("Condition one was satisfied.\n");
    }
    else if (condition2)
    {
        printf("Condition two was satisfied.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Something else happened.\n");
    }
}
```

If you want to print the value of integer variables you can use this syntax.

```
void myFunction(void)
{
     int myValue = 4;
     printf("The value of the myValue variable is: %d.\n", myValue);
}
```

For more information about the `printf` function you can check this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 4):

The variable *does* change its value, but then you immediately exit and terminate the process. The `exit` function does not return.

Comment: I tried to remove the exit(1) as well, but still exitvalue = 0 when I print

Comment: @coava Maybe you should try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Or at least use a debugger to step through the code to see that the condition turns out to be true and the variable is set as you think.

Comment: Yes, and show what `if (some conditions)` is really doing, so we know its result.

Comment: @coava : Place the `exitvalue = 0;` in the else clause, otherwise it will always be zero when the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `return` rather than `exit`. The `return` statement allows to exit a function (with a return value) while `exit` is for leaving the program. Is it what you want?

```
return 0;
```

or

```
return 1;
```

or

```
return exitvalue;
```

Comment: so just directly type `return` without giving value 0 or 1?

Comment: @coava : Yes, except that would not be valid since you declared `functionName()` as returning `int` - the code you posted is not valid for that reason.  Since you are starting learning C, you should know that both the use of global variables and functions with more than one return at the end are generally considered bad practice amongst more enlightened developers.  They are not habits you should aquire "proficiency" at.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of encouraging the bad habit of global variables:

```
void functionName() 
{
    if (some conditions) 
    {
        // some code....
        exitvalue = 1 ;
    }
    else
    {
        exitvalue = 0 ;
    }
}
```

Or just:

```
void functionName() 
{
    exitvalue = 0 ;
    if (some conditions) 
    {
        // some code....
        exitvalue = 1 ;
    }
}
```